# How to Fix "Cannot read property 'substr' of null" on call to initJitsiConference

Tags: angular, webrtc, jitsi, jitsi-meet

I'm attempting to integrate `lib-jitsi-meet` into an Angular (version 7) application and, when calling `initJitsiConference` with an established `JitsiConnection`, am receiving a compile error at the `xmpp.js` level. The source is taken directly from the [example repo](https://github.com/jitsi/lib-jitsi-meet/blob/master/doc/example/example.js), with no modifications made, and can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/drew-thompson/4d93be95a82d054924dad311ed1e26fe).

```
AppComponent_Host.ngfactory.js? [sm]:1 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'substr' of null
at t.value (xmpp.js:409)
at X._init (JitsiConference.js:240)
at new X (JitsiConference.js:118)
at c.initJitsiConference (JitsiConnection.js:103)
```

The stack trace points to these function calls, at `t.value (xmpp.js:409)` and at `new X (JitsiConference.js:118)`, respectively.

```
this.room = this.xmpp.createRoom(this.options.name, config);
```

and

```
return new JitsiConference({
    name,
    config: options,
    connection: this
});
```

Any feedback or advice would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Double check your code about the roomname (first argument of initJitsiConference). It must be :

- Not empty
- Not null
- Only lower case

```
/* const connection = ...YOUR_CONNECTION... */

const roomName = 'conference'
const roomOption = {}

const room = connection.initJitsiConference(roomName, roomOption);
```

You can find a simple example in the «Getting Started» of this page : https://github.com/jitsi/lib-jitsi-meet/blob/master/doc/API.md